# In a QuerySet get the first child Model from a list of Parent Model

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have 2 models Product and Image. A Product can have multiple Image(s), so Image has a FK to product.

I want to get the first image from a list of Product(s)

I have the following queryset:

```
   images = Image.objects.filter(product_id__in=product_home).first()
```

This is not working, because it return just one, and not one per product.

Comment: If image has a `created` field, try this: `Product.objects.select_related('product__image').filter(id__in=product_home).order_by('image__created').distinct('product__image')`

Comment: from a database perspective doesn't query all of them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot test it directly, but maybe this will work:

```
images = Image.objects.filter(product_id__in=product_home).annotate(p=F('product_id')).distinct('p')
```